# Optimize Slow Lon/Lat Query with table joins

Tags: mysql, performance, join, query-optimization, latitude-longitude

We're working on an existing website and we can't re-build the database to be better optimised, so unfortunately we're running a load of 'joins' to link to each table.

We're linking several small tables of temporarily stored postcodes, user accounts, sporting activities, age group, etc.

I'm not good at optimizing SQL but I need this query to run as fast as possible as I think it's causing issues for our server as its being logged in the 'slow log' file. Basically we have Longitude/Latitude stored in a table for a particular user. This Lon/Lat is then checked against a second table that has a list of users with their lon/lat. The recordset then displays the results based on the nearest user. Unfortunately it has a ton of table joins

Info: Query_time: 5  Lock_time: 0  Rows_sent: 10  Rows_examined: 18823691

```
SELECT *,
   ( 3959 * acos
      ( cos
         ( radians(TableA.user_latitude)
      ) * cos
         ( radians( TableB.latitude ) )
        * cos( radians( TableB.longitude ) - radians(TableA.user_longitude) ) + sin( radians(TableA.user_latitude) ) * sin( radians( TableB.latitude ) ) ) )

AS distance FROM
   (
      (
         (
            (
               TableC JOIN TableD on TableC.activity_sport = TableD.sport_ID
            )
         JOIN TableA on TableC.activity_UserID = TableA.user_ID
         )
      LEFT JOIN TableE on TableE.TSageCatID = TableA.user_age
      )
   JOIN TableB on TableB.postcode = 'SE1 7PB'
   )

LEFT JOIN TableF on TableF.log_UserID = TableA.user_ID
WHERE TableA.user_age LIKE '%'
AND TableA.user_gender LIKE '%'
AND TableC.activity_sport LIKE '63'
AND TableC.activity_level LIKE '%'
AND TableA.valid = 1
AND TableA.user_ID != '-1'
AND TableA.user_Level = 'partner'

GROUP BY user_email
HAVING DISTANCE < 50
ORDER BY distance ASC
LIMIT 120, 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the points into buckets and search for nearby points around your location. You can download my php class hilbert-curve @ phpclasses.org. It uses a quadkey and a mercator projection.